# In Unity3D how turning off screen whithout sleep?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, screen, sleep

As in Unity3D turn off the screen without entering sleep mode, so that the application continues to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn off" the screen?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to have Unity run in the background. 
I don't know if this is still common practice, but in the past, many people simply draw a fully black screen to conserve power.

See: https://forum.unity.com/threads/application-runinbackground-is-not-working-on-android.117723/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html

> OnApplicationFocus is called when the application loses or gains focus. Alt-tabbing or Cmd-tabbing can take focus away from the Unity application to another desktop application. This causes the GameObjects to receive an OnApplicationFocus call with the argument set to false. When the user switches back to the Unity application, the GameObjects receive an OnApplicationFocus call with the argument set to true.

You could implement this with the gameobjects you want to continue behaving as you like.